# can the chromecast device be programmed also be used as a sender

Tags: google-cast

I wanted to know if it is possible to program one chromecast device to send video to another chromecast device acting like a receiver. I have browsed the API reference on the Google developer website and it doesn't seem to be supported, but also doesn't say it isn't supported.

Comment: Basicly against the UX theme of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LesVogel-GoogleTVDevRel. It just seems like a natural extension for the device. That would allow for the android/chrome devices to be the hub for all entertainment devices. I was picturing attaching a chromecast device to each media device and having an android tablet control it all. Go from cable to blu-ray to netflix to youtube all controlled by one device. It is a similar concept to what Microsoft is doing with the XBOX One by making it the entertainment hub for your living room.

Comment: @DMC3600

That can already be done though.  If you use the standard Cast action button, you are of course limited to working with a single Chromecast, but if you do a bit more manual coding, you can get a list of all Chromecasts, and connect to all of them simultaneously and control them each manually and individually.  You will need to build your own UI for selecting and controlling them, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible, and probably never will be.  Chromecast devices don't "source' video, they only transfer from wifi to an HDMI output.  it is possible to play the same stream on two different chromecast devices, but there is no way to synchronize them at the moment.  In theory this is something the devices could support.